# JavaScript: JSON Data into the table cell

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I have a table set up using HTML and CSS, with the table having "Row XX" and "Row YY". Next to those cells are "XX" and "YY" in a div, given ID so it is  and

I also have a data file in a JSON format that looks like this (with hundreds of data, but I'll write down only two iterations each).

```
[
  {
    "XX":24,
    "YY":12,
  },
  {
    "XX":15,
    "YY":16,
  },
]
```

My goal is to write a JavaScript file, hoping in an array to export, loop through the data within JSON file into the div ID's in the table, such that
JSON "xx" goes into div ID = "XX" inside the table
JSON "yy" goes into div ID = "YY" inside the table

there are hundreds of data, so I am thinking somewhat of a for-loop? 
and since these data have to be stored, I am thinking it'll have to be inside an array?

JS Fiddle of the table is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5acaemf6/)

**Please note: I do not want to add extra columns or rows as you loop through the JSON data. I want the unique ID within the cell of the table to refresh and update to the new data as data is being looped through**

Comment: An ID should be seen as a unique identifier, your JSON code seems to have multiple XX & YY. Do you wish to generate the table completely? Are the columns fixed, or could some values per row be missing?

Comment: There are multiple XX and YY, my goal is to loop through these data, for example, every 2 seconds it goes progresses from such as first XX to second XX to third XX.... and display it in the table cell each time it changes. I believe that columns are fixed

Comment: So, none of the answers below can help you? I'm still unsure if you wish to display multiple rows with the same XX/YY ids or if you wish to change to show 1 row with concatening data, or you wish to show 1 row with each time the latest data you received :)

Comment: oh, it will be a multiple rows with different XX/YY ids. There are about 8 different variables that needs to be displayed in each placement of xx / yy IDs that should display latest data received. I'm actually trying the ones below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery to do this.  Assuming that all your data are going into the two rows xx and yy, just set up a table with rows xx and yy.  You do not need a `div` inside the table cells.  Then you can use jQuery to insert `td` with each data point, in the appropriate row.  Here's an example:

```
    <table>
        <tr  id="xx">
        </tr>
        <tr  id="yy">               
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then do something like this (I have created a sample data and called it a):

```
var a = [ {"xx": 24, "yy": 12}, {"xx": 15, "yy": 16}];

for (i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    $('#xx').append("<td>"+a[i].xx+"</td>");
    $('#yy').append("<td>"+a[i].yy+"</td>");
```

## }

To replace values in existing table cells, with the table as follows:

```
    <table>
        <tr >
            <td>Row xx</td>
            <td id="xx"></td>               
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row yy</td>
            <td id="yy"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

then, just change the for-loop to this:

```
for (i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    $('#xx').html(a[i].xx);
    $('#yy').html(a[i].yy);
}
```

Comment: My apology, the question I have written may not have been accurate. So, what I want to do is not to extend the table rows for each data incoming but to have only 2 columns, where the second column has a specific ID. For example, the first cell should only have ONE value Xx and should refresh and display the next data set in the JSON when it goes through the loop

Comment: Okay, I think I understand what you are trying to do - you want to replace the values in the xx and yy cells.  I have added code to do this in my original response. See my response above.

Comment: Not sure where I am doing wrong [link](https://jsfiddle.net/5acaemf6/10/)

https://jsfiddle.net/5acaemf6/10/

Comment: I checked your link. It works. In JSFiddle, make sure you are setting jQuery at the top left, from the drop-down list.

Comment: Hi rby, I see, thank you !! but it only gives me the final value of xx = 15 and yy = 16, How can I make it start from xx = 24 , yy = 12 and it goes to the next one after a second or two? As a loop.
Also, is it possible to store these in arrays? Because I will need them later

Comment: If you want to implement some type of a pause/timer, you can use Window.setInterval(function, delay in ms), which will repeatedly call the function passed with the delay given.  If you do this, you also need to consider when/how you terminate these calls.  An alternative would be to add a button or some other event listener (click) on which you would access the next elements.  And yes you can save the values in an array or object - for example, do var xx_yy = { "xx":[], "yy": [] }; and then you can add corresponding value by dong xx_yy.xx.push(value for xx); and xx_yy.yy.push(value for yy).

Comment: I am so sorry.... that got me completely lost. I'm reading the w3school about timing and array objects but , it's hard

Comment: It's okay, whatever questions you have, search SO or other sites for explanations but if you still need help just post a new question on SO and someone will help.  I hope I was at least of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You can test :

data is your json

```
var $item =  [];
var $items = $(null);  // Your future html result
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
   $item[i] = $($($.parseHTML('<div id="'+i+'">'+item+'</div>')));
   $items = $items.add($item[i]);
});​
```

Comment: Hi, do I need to assign data = json somehow?

Comment: or just $.each(filename.json, function(i, item){}

Answer (score 0):

Use two for loops. First for loop is to loop through xx. Second for yy.

```
var data = [
    {"xx":2, "yy":3},{"xx":5, "yy":2}
];


for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    $('table tr:eq(0)').append('<td>' + data[i]['xx'] + '</td>');
}

for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
    $('table tr:eq(1)').append('<td>' + data[i]['yy'] + '</td>');
}
```

Check [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divyanthj/94st5on5/1/). Keep adding new data to the `data` array.

Comment: Hi, so I have basically 100s of data of "xx" and "yy". But my goal is, when looping through these data, I want the unique IDs within the cell "xx" and "yy" to refresh and update to the next value and so on, not to add extra columns of the table. Sorry for the unclear question